# Apache Cassandra not showing table once created

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have created a table in Cassandra and when trying to access it Column family not found error pops up. Trying again to create the table showing the Table already exist error. I am using Cassandra 2.1.7 (most stable version), CQLSH 5.0.1, CQL Spec 3.2.0. Why its showing strange behavior?

[image]

Comment: That is strange.  But you are using Cassandra on Window$ (which is not supported...and for good reason).  What does your `system.log` say?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: datastax provides the windows msi installer for windows. Why its not supported

Comment: If you're just running it for development on your own machine, that *should* be fine.  But some people see the MSI and think they can build a prod Cassandra server on Windows.  Problems happen because NTFS is more restrictive when it comes to allowing deletes/updates to files that other procs have hard links for.  Cassandra also uses memory mapped file I/O, which is problematic on Windows for similar reasons.

Comment: Cassandra on Windows is basically supported. I believe it becomes a first class platform for 2.2. I suspect this may be related to case sensitivity or schema propagation, though - does nodetool gossipinfo show matching schemas on all nodes?